# Chrome freezes system with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, gnome, google-chrome, freeze, 20.04

I began having this issue with an update in 19.04, and it has persisted with 19.10 and now 20.04. Some websites cause Chrome to completely freeze the system, with no mouse or keyboard use possible. The system restarts after about 10 seconds.

I have tried Chromium and gotten the same results. I have disabled hardware acceleration and other Chrome settings that are common in these threads, but they do not help. Some websites cause this, and others don't. Facebook, for example, will always cause this freeze. Annoyingly, Gmail frequently does, too. Twitter does not.

My system: Intel i7-7820x, nVidia GeForce GTX 1070, 16 gb ram, 64 bit

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

**To those out there who might have problems in the future, and should be considered more of a forum post rather than an explicit fix or answer**

This problem is a known issue for several users, and there seems to be no clear-cut solution. Some can install a package to deal with it (unfortunately i cannot find a post with this link at this moment), and some might even get over the problem by disabeling hardware acceleration by running `chrome --disable gpu` (of sorts), or doing it directly in chrome settings, but for my case, this is not a fix which have seemed to work.

Updates can cause the flaw, and the latest update (Mar 2022) have yet again forced me to downgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 to find out that eventually the problem persisted. It might be a kernel problem and again, it can just be Chrome "magic" or rather "sorcery" appearing from update to update.

**Conclusion**

Perhaps chrome is, after all, really badly supported by our favorite operating system, and it might be that Firefox is just the way to go. Some makes it work, some don't - but at least I have found peace with using another browser.

Comment: downgrade to Ubuntu 20.04  What are you downgrading from?